Test Class Inbound Change Set Errors: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Unexpected error message: Script-thrown exception
I've been trying to get an Apex Controller and Test Class into Production, but just can't get passed the same errors, regardless of changes on the user profile type or utilising setMessage() to store the error messages. If anyone has any suggestions, tat would be very much appreciated.
Error messages:

testNoOpportunityProducts:
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Unexpected error message: Script-thrown exception
Stack Trace: Class.SpecificationSheetControllerTest.testNoOpportunityProducts: line 212, column 1


testNoSpecifications:
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Unexpected error message: Script-thrown exception
Stack Trace: Class.SpecificationSheetControllerTest.testNoSpecifications: line 94, column 1


testWithSpecifications:
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Unexpected error message: Script-thrown exception
Stack Trace: Class.SpecificationSheetControllerTest.testWithSpecifications: line 180, column 1

Thank you,
Tim
Apex Controller Snippets:
1:
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<WrapperClass> getOpportunityProductsWithSpecifications(Id specSheetId) {
        // Check if the current user has read access to the Specification_Sheet__c object
        if (!Schema.sObjectType.Specification_Sheet__c.fields.Opportunity__c.isAccessible()) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have access to view Specification Sheets.');
        }

2:
// Check if the current user has read access to the OpportunityLineItem object and fields
if (!Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.isAccessible() ||
    !Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.PricebookEntryId.isAccessible() ||
    !Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.Quantity.isAccessible() ||
    !Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.SortOrder.isAccessible() ||
    !Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.Opportunity_Product_Name_Editible__c.isAccessible() ||
    !Schema.sObjectType.OpportunityLineItem.fields.Description.isAccessible()) 
    {
        throw new AuraHandledException('You do not have access to view Opportunity Products.');
    }

3:
 @AuraEnabled
public static void deleteSpecification(Id specId) {
    try {
        Specification__c specToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :specId LIMIT 1];
        delete specToDelete;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException('Error deleting specification: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}

The Test Class:
@isTest
private class SpecificationSheetControllerTest {

    // Helper method to create a Specification Sheet
    private static Specification_Sheet__c createSpecificationSheet(Opportunity opp) {
        Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = new Specification_Sheet__c(
            Opportunity__c = opp.Id,
            Name = 'Test Specification Sheet'
        );
        insert specSheet;
        return specSheet;
    }

    private static User createTestUser() {
        Profile sysAdminProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
        if (sysAdminProfile == null) {
            throw new System.AssertException('System Administrator profile not found.');
        }
        User testUser = new User(
            Alias = 'tuser',
            LastName = 'test',
            Email = 'testuser' + String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()) + '@example.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            ProfileId = sysAdminProfile.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'testuser' + String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()) + '@example.com'
        );
        insert testUser;
        return testUser;
    }

    @isTest
    static void testNoSpecifications() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            Id standardPricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
            Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Unleashed Pricebook', IsActive = true);
            insert customPricebook;

            Product2 product1 = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product 1', IsActive = true);
            insert product1;

            PricebookEntry standardPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = standardPricebookId,
                Product2Id = product1.Id,
                UnitPrice = 100,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert standardPbe;

            PricebookEntry customPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                Product2Id = product1.Id,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert customPbe;

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opportunity',
                CloseDate = Date.today().addMonths(1),
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id, // Ensure valid Record Type ID
                Type = 'New Business',
                Generate_Specification_Questions__c = true
            );
            insert opp;

            Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = createSpecificationSheet(opp);

            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                Quantity = 10,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                PricebookEntryId = customPbe.Id,
                Opportunity_Product_Name_Editible__c = 'Test Product 1',
                SortOrder = 1,
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id
            );
            insert oli;

            Test.startTest();
            try {
                List<SpecificationSheetController.WrapperClass> result = SpecificationSheetController.getOpportunityProductsWithSpecifications(specSheet.Id);
                Test.stopTest();

                System.assertEquals(1, result.size(), 'Expected one wrapper class in the result.');
                System.assertEquals(oli.Id, result[0].product.Id, 'Expected product ID to match.');
                System.assertEquals(0, result[0].specifications.size(), 'Expected no specifications for the Opportunity Product.');
            } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
                System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Access denied to Specifications'), 'Unexpected error message: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testWithSpecifications() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            Id standardPricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
            Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Unleashed Pricebook', IsActive = true);
            insert customPricebook;

            Product2 product1 = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product 1', IsActive = true);
            insert product1;

            PricebookEntry standardPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = standardPricebookId,
                Product2Id = product1.Id,
                UnitPrice = 100,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert standardPbe;

            PricebookEntry customPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                Product2Id = product1.Id,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert customPbe;

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opportunity',
                CloseDate = Date.today().addMonths(1),
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id, // Ensure valid Record Type ID
                Type = 'New Business',
                Generate_Specification_Questions__c = true
            );
            insert opp;

            Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = createSpecificationSheet(opp);

            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                Quantity = 10,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                PricebookEntryId = customPbe.Id,
                Opportunity_Product_Name_Editible__c = 'Test Product 1',
                SortOrder = 1,
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id
            );
            insert oli;

            Template_Specification__c templateSpec = new Template_Specification__c(Name = 'Template Spec');
            insert templateSpec;

            Specification__c spec1 = new Specification__c(
                Opportunity_Product__c = oli.Id,
                Name = 'Spec 1',
                Answer__c = 'Answer 1',
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id,
                Template_Specification_Question__c = templateSpec.Id
            );
            insert spec1;

            Specification__c spec2 = new Specification__c(
                Opportunity_Product__c = oli.Id,
                Name = 'Spec 2',
                Answer__c = 'Answer 2',
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id,
                Template_Specification_Question__c = templateSpec.Id
            );
            insert spec2;

            Test.startTest();
            try {
                List<SpecificationSheetController.WrapperClass> result = SpecificationSheetController.getOpportunityProductsWithSpecifications(specSheet.Id);
                Test.stopTest();

                System.assertEquals(1, result.size(), 'Expected one wrapper class in the result.');
                System.assertEquals(oli.Id, result[0].product.Id, 'Expected product ID to match.');
                System.assertEquals(2, result[0].specifications.size(), 'Expected two specifications for the Opportunity Product.');
            } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
                System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Access denied to Specifications'), 'Unexpected error message: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testNoOpportunityProducts() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Unleashed Pricebook', IsActive = true);
            insert customPricebook;

            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opportunity',
                CloseDate = Date.today().addMonths(1),
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id, // Ensure valid Record Type ID
                Type = 'New Business',
                Generate_Specification_Questions__c = true
            );
            insert opp;

            Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = createSpecificationSheet(opp);

            Test.startTest();
            try {
                List<SpecificationSheetController.WrapperClass> result = SpecificationSheetController.getOpportunityProductsWithSpecifications(specSheet.Id);
                Test.stopTest();

                System.assertEquals(0, result.size(), 'Expected no wrapper classes in the result.');
            } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
                System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Access denied to Specifications'), 'Unexpected error message: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testReorderSpecifications() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            // Create an Opportunity
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opportunity',
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id, // Ensure valid Record Type ID
                Type = 'New Business',
                Generate_Specification_Questions__c = true
            );
            insert opp;

            // Create a Specification Sheet
            Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = new Specification_Sheet__c(
                Name = 'Spec Sheet for Reorder',
                Opportunity__c = opp.Id
            );
            insert specSheet;

            // Create Specifications with different Sort Order
            Specification__c spec1 = new Specification__c(
                Name = 'Spec 1',
                Sort_Order__c = 1,
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id
            );
            insert spec1;

            Specification__c spec2 = new Specification__c(
                Name = 'Spec 2',
                Sort_Order__c = 2,
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id
            );
            insert spec2;

            // Reorder Specifications
            Test.startTest();
            SpecificationSheetController.reorderSpecifications(spec1.Id, spec2.Id);
            Test.stopTest();

            // Fetch updated Specifications
            Specification__c updatedSpec1 = [SELECT Id, Sort_Order__c FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :spec1.Id];
            Specification__c updatedSpec2 = [SELECT Id, Sort_Order__c FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :spec2.Id];

            // Assert that the Sort Order has been swapped
            System.assertEquals(2, updatedSpec1.Sort_Order__c, 'The Sort Order for spec1 should be 2');
            System.assertEquals(1, updatedSpec2.Sort_Order__c, 'The Sort Order for spec2 should be 1');
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testGetUpdateNotificationPicklistValues() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            List<Map<String, String>> picklistValues = SpecificationSheetController.getUpdateNotificationPicklistValues();
            System.assert(!picklistValues.isEmpty(), 'Picklist values should not be empty');
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testDeleteSpecification() {
        User testUser = createTestUser();
        System.runAs(testUser) {
            // Create a Standard Price Book Entry
            Id standardPricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

            // Create a Product
            Product2 product = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product', IsActive = true);
            insert product;

            // Create a PricebookEntry for the Standard Price Book
            PricebookEntry standardPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = standardPricebookId,
                Product2Id = product.Id,
                UnitPrice = 100,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert standardPbe;

            // Create a custom Pricebook
            Pricebook2 customPricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Custom Pricebook', IsActive = true);
            insert customPricebook;

            // Create a PricebookEntry for the custom Pricebook
            PricebookEntry customPbe = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id,
                Product2Id = product.Id,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert customPbe;

            // Create an Opportunity
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Test Opportunity for Deletion',
                StageName = 'Prospecting',
                CloseDate = Date.today().addMonths(1),
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' LIMIT 1].Id, // Ensure valid Record Type ID
                Type = 'New Business',
                Generate_Specification_Questions__c = true,
                Pricebook2Id = customPricebook.Id
            );
            insert opp;

            // Create a Specification Sheet
            Specification_Sheet__c specSheet = new Specification_Sheet__c(
                Name = 'Spec Sheet for Deletion',
                Opportunity__c = opp.Id
            );
            insert specSheet;

            // Create an OpportunityLineItem
            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                Quantity = 1,
                UnitPrice = 110,
                PricebookEntryId = customPbe.Id,
                Opportunity_Product_Name_Editible__c = product.Name,
                SortOrder = 1,
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id
            );
            insert oli;

            // Create a Specification record
            Specification__c spec = new Specification__c(
                Name = 'Spec to Delete',
                Specification_Sheet__c = specSheet.Id,
                Opportunity_Product__c = oli.Id
            );
            insert spec;

            // Verify the Specification record exists before deletion
            Specification__c existingSpec = [SELECT Id FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :spec.Id LIMIT 1];
            System.assertNotEquals(null, existingSpec, 'The Specification should exist before deletion');

            // Delete the Specification
            Test.startTest();
            SpecificationSheetController.deleteSpecification(spec.Id);
            Test.stopTest();

            // Verify that the Specification has been deleted
            List<Specification__c> deletedSpecs = [SELECT Id FROM Specification__c WHERE Id = :spec.Id];
            System.assertEquals(0, deletedSpecs.size(), 'The Specification should have been deleted');
        }
    }
}


Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read How to Ask. It looks like the underlying class that you are testing is handling exceptions different from what you are expecting in your test class, is it possible to include that Apex in your question, or at least snippets of it? It is also worth pointing out that you have redundant Assert statements in your class if you are specifically trying to cause an error in the underlying class, as anything in the try block after the error is thrown won't be executed.

Hi @CallumMacErlich, thank you very much for your quick response and for the feedback on the redundant Assert statements, I'll look at removing them. I'll add some snippets of the Ape Class to the question. Tim

Thanks for adding those snippets @Timothy-Hayward, from those though there is a mismatch with the errors you are throwing versus what you are asserting in your test class. For example, the first error is throwing an error with the message 'You do not have access to view Specification Sheets.' but you are asserting that it contains 'Access denied to Specifications'. Could you try ensure that those are matching? I would also have expected these tests to fail in lower environments, were they actually run before attempting to deploy to Production?

Thanks @CallumMacErlich, thanks for pointing out the mismatch. I'll check and update them to see how it goes. It makes sense given the error messages. I'm not sure why it hasn't been detected prior to being uploaded into the Production. Anyway, I'll see how it goes and let you know. Thanks, Tim
